# Які риси давньоруської мови збереглися в сучасній українській?

Tags: історія-мови

- Давноминулий час
- Друга палаталізація
- Кличний відмінок

А що ще?

Comment: Це запитання передбачає відповідь у вигляді списку, що тягне суб'єктивні відповіді. Та і сама тематика досить широка. Думаю, це запитання варто розбити на кілька менших за розміром, але answerable і більш об'єктивних.

Comment: @bytebuster, з одного боку так — а з іншого, такий список не буде великим, тобто наврядчи це too broad. А як Ви маєте на увазі розбити на кілька менших за розміром, але answerable і більш об'єктивних?

Comment: Хм… До речі, зараз зрозумів, що відповіддю на питання, мабуть, буде «**більшість** (адже українська є нащадком равньоруської і наслідує велику частину лексики, граматики тощо)». Можливо, Ви мали на увазі риси, що є зараз специфічними для української (тобто не збереглися в більшості, чи принаймні в частині, інших нащадків давньоруської (або й такі, що й в українській до кінця не збереглися, а залишилися лише рудименти (як от двоїна)))?

Comment: @Sasha,
Не знаю, щодо більшості.
Тоді спочатку треба визначитися з терміном **Давньоруська мова**, я так називаю писемну мову Русі, але ж в основі сучасної мови лежить живе мовлення.

Comment: @Oleg, добре, може, я не правий. Просто мені інтуїтивно здалося, що формально питання вимагає перерахувати все, що спільне з писемною мовою Русі (а це величезний пласт лексики й граматики, хоч розмовна й відрізняється від писемної) — а Вас при цьому цікавить лише те, що в давноруської спільне **лише** саме з українською (якщо воно спільне і з російською/білоруською — то нецікаво). Але, може, я помилився, і Вас цікавить справді все.

Answer (score 8):

Що називати "давньоруською" мовою - окрема тема для обговорення і суперечок. ;)

Але ось цікава стаття про що в українській зберіглося від праслов'янської:
http://litopys.org.ua/pivtorak/pivt05.htm

Цитую уривок звідти:

"Оскільки переважна більшість української етномовної території збігається зі східним ареалом слов'янської прабатьківщини, цілком природно, що українці успадкували матеріальну й духовну культури своїх предків-праслов'ян цього реґіону, а українська мова перейняла від праслов'янської значний специфічний лексичний фонд і чимало фонетичних та граматичних (насамперед, морфологічних) рис, які в інших слов'янських мовах замінилися новими, а в нас вони склали найдавнішу групу українських мовних особливостей. Серед них найважливіші:

1) закінчення -у в род. відмінку однини іменників чол. роду з давньою основою на u: солоду, мéду, дóму, вéрху, пóлу;

2) закінчення -ові, -еві (-єві) в дав. відмінку однини іменників чол. роду цієї самої групи типу сóлодові, мéдові, дóмові, а потім — і всіх інших іменників чол. роду;

3) чергування приголосних г, к, x зі свистячими з, с, ц у дав. та місц. відмінках однини іменників: дЂвцЂ» слузЂ, на березЂ, на рЂцЂ, в книзЂ;

4) кличний відмінок іменників: жено, друже, княже, брате, земле, владико, учителю;

5) закінчення -ої в род. відмінку однини прикметників жін. роду: велúкої, дóброї, святої, пáгубної;

6) форми дав. відмінка займенників мені, тобі, собі;

7) форми 3-ї особи дієслів теперішнього і простого майбутнього часів І дієвідміни: мóже, убивáє, ідé, живé, поучáє;

8) закінчення -мо в дієсловах 1-ї особи множини теперішнього і майбутнього часів: даємó, постáвимо, не питáємо, помагáємо та ін.;"